# SQL Server 2000 XML PATH('') error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000, for-xml

```
SELECT
**FIELDS**
AS [text()] --Stops the XMLPATH line rendering output as XML
FROM #temp
WHERE  **CONDITIONS**
FOR XML PATH('')
```

This doesn't work in SQL server 2000 (unsupported).
I have tried using `FOR XML RAW` but it returns loads of useless information. i.e:

```
 <row text x0028 x0029="blah, blah"> <row text x0028 x0029="blah">
```

The above code currently returns a concatenated string(made up of multiple columns of varying types) from every single row in the table.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Might be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Useful, but unfortunately it covers it from 2000 to 2005 rather than the other way around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concatenation in SQL Server 2000:

```
declare @s varchar(8000);
set @s = '';

select @s = @s + field1 + field2 + field3
from #temp
where ...
order by ...;

select @s;
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius.. why do I never try the easy option first! Saved me a lot of hair pulling trying to extract items from the generated XML!

Answer (score 3):

The `XML` datatype isn't supported in 2000, it was introduced in 2005.

SQL 2000 did introduce the [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), but it only supported `RAW`, `AUTO`, and `EXPLICIT`

Comment: I know, that's why I'm trying (and failing) to find an alternative :(

Answer (score 0):

You've to define some text or character inside **FOR XML PATH(' ')** like, 
`FOR XML PATH('abc')`. You can also use `FOR XML RAW('abc')` for outputting raw XML.